# Django Template Query Set and filters

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

In my view, I have a model that returns all instances of a model that has a foreign key to user. This view renders a profile page where the model.user is checked against the request.user, if it matches, it prints out information on that model on the profile page.

This is what I have in my views.:

```
@login_required(login_url='loginpage_company')
@allowed_users_company(allowed_roles=['company'])
def profile_company(request):
print(request.user)
companies = Company.objects.all()

responses = Response.objects.all()

context = {
    'companies': companies,
    #'company_reviews': company_reviews,
    #'total_reviews': total_reviews,
    'responses': responses,
    'info': "No company claimed yet",
    'infor': 'Not Available',
       
    
}
return render(request, 'companyusers/profile_company.html', context)
```

for my models I have the following.

```
class Company(models.Model):
Online_Merchant = 'merch'
Education = 'edu'
Transportation = 'trans'
Hospitalism = 'hosp'
Healthcare = 'health'
Construction = 'const'
Blog = 'blog'
Finance = 'fin'
Media = 'media'
Government_Agency = 'agency'
Other = 'other'
Manufacturing = 'manufacturing'
sector = [
    (Online_Merchant, 'Online Merchant'),
    (Education, 'Education'),
    (Transportation, 'Transportation'),
    (Hospitalism, 'Hospitalism'),
    (Healthcare, 'Healthcare'),
    (Construction, 'Construction'),
    (Blog, 'Blog'),
    (Finance, 'Finance'),
    (Media, 'Media'),
    (Manufacturing, 'Manufacturing'),
    (Government_Agency, 'Government Agency'),
    (Other, 'Other')
]
Free = 'Free'
Premium = 'Premium'
package = [
    (Free, 'Free'),
    (Premium, 'Premium')
]
Abuja = 'Abuja'
Abia = 'Abia'
Adamawa = 'Adamawa'
Akwa_Ibom = 'Akwa Ibom'
Anambra = 'Anambra'
Bauchi = 'Bauchi'
Bayelsa = 'Bayelsa'
Benue = 'Benue'
Borno = 'Borno'
Cross_River = 'Cross River'
Delta = 'Delta'
Ebonyi = 'Ebonyi'
Edo = 'Edo'
Ekiti = 'Ekiti'
Enugu = 'Enugu'
Gombe = 'Gombe'
Imo = 'Imo'
Jigawa = 'Jigawa'
Kaduna = 'Kaduna'
Kano = 'Kano'
Katsina = 'Katsina'
Kebbi = 'Kebbi'
Kogi = 'Kogi'
Kwara = 'Kwara'
Lagos = 'Lagos'
Nasarawa = 'Nasarawa'
Niger = 'Niger'
Ogun = 'Ogun'
Ondo = 'Ondo'
Osun = 'Osun'
Oyo = 'Ibadan'
Plateau = 'Plateau'
Rivers = 'Rivers'
Sokoto = 'Sokoto'
Taraba = 'Taraba'
Yobe = 'Yobe'
Zamfara = 'Zamfara'

state = [
    (Abuja, 'Abuja'),
    (Abia, 'Abia'), 
    (Adamawa, 'Adamawa'),   
    (Akwa_Ibom, 'Akwa Ibom'),
    (Anambra, 'Anambra'),
    (Bauchi, 'Bauchi'),
    (Bayelsa, 'Bayelsa'),
    (Benue, 'Benue'),
    (Borno, 'Borno'),
    (Cross_River, 'Cross River'),
    (Delta, 'Delta'),
    (Ebonyi, 'Ebonyi'),
    (Edo, 'Edo'),
    (Ekiti, 'Ekiti'),
    (Enugu, 'Enugu'),
    (Gombe, 'Gombe'),
    (Imo, 'Imo'),
    (Jigawa, 'Jigawa'),
    (Kaduna, 'Kaduna'),
    (Kano, 'Kano'),
    (Katsina, 'Katsina'),
    (Kebbi, 'Kebbi'),
    (Kogi, 'Kogi'),
    (Kwara, 'Kwara'),
    (Lagos, 'Lagos'),
    (Nasarawa, 'Nasarawa'),
    (Niger, 'Niger'),
    (Ogun, 'Ogun'),
    (Ondo, 'Ondo'),
    (Osun, 'Osun'),
    (Oyo, 'Ibadan'),
    (Plateau, 'Plateau'),
    (Rivers, 'Rivers'),
    (Sokoto, 'Sokoto'),
    (Taraba, 'Taraba'),
    (Yobe, 'Yobe'),
    (Zamfara, 'Zamfara')
]

user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, verbose_name='Company User')
company_sector = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=sector, default=Online_Merchant)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
company_description = models.TextField()
company_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='company_logos', blank=True, null=True)
company_state = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=state, default=Lagos)
company_address = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
average_rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
total_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
company_website = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
company_email = models.EmailField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
company_phone = models.CharField(max_length=500)
package_chosen = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=package, default=Free)
featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
advert = models.BooleanField(default=False)
premium = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.company_name
```

This is what I have in the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% include "nav_bar.html" %}

{% block greeting %}                        
    <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="{% url 'contact' %}"><i class="fas fa-envelope" style="font-size:20px; padding-right: 4px; color:#2196F3"></i>Contact Us</a>
    </li>
{% endblock greeting %}

{% block section %} 


    <section class="mt-2 bg-white mx-2">
        
        <div class="container-fluid border-0 text-justify">
            <div class="row">
                <span class="font-weight-bold px-2 py-1 mx-auto text-danger">...Created with<span class="h3"> &hearts;</span>... Because we understand that behind every review, there is a hearty experience...</span>
            </div>
            <div class="row mx-2">
                <div class="col-md-5 mb-2">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 23rem;">
                        <img src="{{request.user.userprofilecompany.profile_photo.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="profile picture">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Company Name: &nbsp; {{request.user.userprofilecompany.company_name}}</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Username: {{request.user.username}} </br><span class="font-weight-sm">this is publicly visible</span></p>
                            <p class="card-text">Fullname: &nbsp;{{request.user.last_name}},&nbsp;{{request.user.first_name}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Designation: &nbsp; {{request.user.userprofilecompany.designation}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Email: &nbsp;{{request.user.email}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Phone:&nbsp;{{request.user.userprofilecompany.phone}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Location: &nbsp;{{request.user.userprofilecompany.location}}</p>
                            <p class="card-text">Package: &nbsp;{{request.user.userprofilecompany.package}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Upgrade</a></p>

                            
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                            <a href="{% url 'settings_company' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Go to Settings</a></br>
                            <p class="card-text"></p>
                            <a href="{% url 'logoutpage_company' %}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Logout</a></br>
                        </div>
                     </div>

                </div>
                
                {% for company in companies %}
                    {% if company.user == request.user %}
                
                <div class="col-md mb-2">
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            
                            <div class="card text-center  mb-3"> 
                                <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Total Reviews</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title">{{ company.review_set.all.count }}</h3>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h3 class="card-title"></h3>
                                </div>
                                
                                <button class="btn btn-info font-weight-bold btn-sm" id="tm-reviews">View Reviews and Responses</button>
                            </div>

                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            
                                <div class="card  mb-3" > 
                                    <div class="card-header text-center text-white bg-info">
                                        <h5 class="card-title ">Statistics</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="py-2 font-weight-bold px-2">
                                        <p class="card-text">Average Rating:&nbsp; | &nbsp; <i id="tm-average_rating">{{company.average_rating}}</i><i>/5</i> </p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Remarks: &nbsp; | &nbsp;<i id="tm-remarks" class=""></i></p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Likes: &nbsp; | &nbsp; like count number</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Dislikes: &nbsp; | &nbsp; dislike count number</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Average Rating:&nbsp; | &nbsp; 4/5 </p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Remarks: &nbsp; | &nbsp;Satisfactory</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Views: &nbsp; | &nbsp; 10</p>
                                        
                                        <p class="card-text"><h6 class=" font-weight-bold">Claimed Company:&nbsp; <span class= "text-primary"><a class="text-decoration-none" href="{% url 'detail' company.id %}" target="_blank"> {{company.company_name}} </a> </span> </h5></p>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <button class="btn btn-info font-weight-bold btn-sm" id="tm-reviews">Click to Get Noticed</button>
                                    
                                </div>                      

                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row" id="tm-display-reviews">
                            <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            
                                <div style="font-size: small;" class="card text-center  mb-3"> 
                                    <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
                                        <h5 class="card-title">Details</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        {% for review in company.review_set.all %}
                                        <div  class=" py-2">
                                            <p class="card-text ">Name: &nbsp; {{review.user | capfirst }} Rating: {{review.rating}}/5 &nbsp; | &nbsp; Date added: <span class="text-danger"> {{ review.date_added }}</span></p>
                                            <p class="card-text">  Review: &nbsp; {{review.review_text}} </p>
                                        
                                        
                                        <!-- check to see if there is a reponse under this review to know whether
                                         to show the button -->
                                        {% for response in review.response_set.all %} 
                                            {% empty %}                                            
                                        <p class="card-text"><a href="{% url 'response' review.id %}"><button id="tm-respond" class="btn btn-outline-primary font-weight-bold btn-sm">respond to this review</button></a></p>
                                            
                                        {% endfor %}
                                       
                                        {% for response in responses%}
                                        {% if response.review == review %}
                                        <p class="card-text bg-light font-italic">{{response.review.company | capfirst }} responded: {{response}} on: {{response.date_added}}</p>
                                        <hr>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        
                                        {% endfor %}
                                        
                                        </div>
                                                                                                                   
                                    
                                    
                                    
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                    
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                    
                    {% endif %}
                    
                {% endfor %}
               
                
                <div class="col-md mb-2">
                    <!-- The problem is here. It seems to rund the code over and over again-->
                      {% for company in companies %}
                      {% if company.user != request.user%}
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            
                            <div class="card text-center  mb-3"> 
                                <div class="card-header text-white bg-info">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">Total Reviews</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <p class="card-text"> You have not claimed a company yet.</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"> You need to claim a company to view its statistis here.</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"> You need to have your company listed to claim it.</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"> If your company is already listed on our site, kindly email us on:</p>
                                    <p class="card-text"> <a href="mailto:info@crediblereviews.ng">info@crediblereviews.ng</a></p>
                                </div>
                                
                                
                                
                                
                               
                            </div>

                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md mb-2">
                            
                                <div class="card  mb-3" > 
                                    <div class="card-header text-center text-white bg-info">
                                        <h5 class="card-title ">Statistics</h5>
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <div class="py-2 font-weight-bold px-2">
                                        <p class="card-text">Average Rating:&nbsp; | &nbsp; <i id="tm-average_rating">{{infor}}</i> </p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Remarks: &nbsp; | &nbsp;<i id="tm-remarks" class="">{{infor}}</i></p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Likes: &nbsp; | &nbsp; {{infor}}</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Dislikes: &nbsp; | &nbsp; {{infor}}</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Average Rating:&nbsp; | &nbsp; {{infor}} </p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Remarks: &nbsp; | &nbsp;{{infor}}</p>
                                        <p class="card-text">Total Views: &nbsp; | &nbsp; {{infor}}</p>
                                        
                                        <p class="card-text"><h6 class=" text-warning font-weight-bold">{{info}}:&nbsp; <span style="font-size: small;" class= "text-info"> Email us to claim a company </span> </h5></p>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    
                                    <button class="btn btn-info font-weight-bold btn-sm" id="tm-reviews">Click to Get Noticed</button>
                                    
                                </div>                      

                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    <!---->
                    
                </div>
                
               
               
                
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
    {% endblock section %}
    {% block article %}
    
    {% endblock article %}
```

The problem is the last loop it seems to print the code as many times as there are instances of the model that doesnt match the condition. This is not what I want. I want to be able to check if request.user is not equal to company.user and print the last division. Thanks so much for the help...

Comment: please fix your indentations

Answer (score 0):

It is a misuse of Django framework to do data filtering in the templates. As it is a simple filtering (or data routing) you can simply filter the unwanted campaigns out by using `campaigns.filter(user=request.user)` instead of `campaigns` while creating your context.

Comment: Thanks Ali for your suggestion. But request.user.id woul always never be equal to company.id. so that part of the code would run in the two instances in the template. Is there no way to query the companies in the template from the context dictionary in the view to return only company where company.user = a particular user ie. request.user

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ali for your help. but selecting where user=request.user would raise an exception saying: reference before assignment. I tried the try and except block for this no way.

I finally used javascript to solve the issue. In the model for my users, I inserted a boolean field. Javascript will now check for this field to know whether to hide or show the division. It works just fine the way I want it.